# C# terminology help needed

Tags: c#

Recently I ran into this code but I don't know the terminology so I couldn't search on Google to learn more about this coding style.

Here's the code:

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject()
{
   Name = "name",
   Value = 10
};
```

Does anyone know what is this called in C#?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is called an [Object Initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)

From the MSDN:

> You can use object initializers to initialize type objects in a
>   declarative manner without explicitly invoking a constructor for the
>   type.

Answer (score 3):

It's called [initializer syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) and it is essentially doing the same thing as the following, but in a single expression:

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
someObject.Name = "name";
someObject.Value = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called Object initializer . See documentation for [Object initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)